Clojure Malli mutually recursive structures along with declarative merge
Trying to work with declarative :merge along with mutual recursion with :ref but failing either with invalid-ref or invalid-schema
Here is an example of something i would like to have:
(def ping-pong-registry
  {::ping [:maybe [:merge
                   [:map
                    [:value [:= "ping"]]
                    [:person string?]]
                   [:map
                    [:child [:ref ::pong]]]]]
   ::pong [:maybe [:merge
                    [:map
                     [:value [:= "pong"]]
                     [:bot string?]]
                    [:map
                     [:child [:ref ::ping]]]]]})

(def ping-pong-schema
  (m/schema [:schema {:registry ping-pong-registry} ::ping])) ; :malli.core/invalid-schema

(m/validate ping-pong-schema
            {:value "ping"
             :person "Jane"
             :child {:value "pong"
                     :bot "c-3po"
                     :child {:value "ping"
                             :person "Jane"
                             :child {:value "pong" 
                                     :bot "c-3po"
                                     :child {:value "ping"
                                             :person "Jane"
                                             :child nil}}}}})

Note this is just an example, in reality merge is needed since schemas are defined elsewhere. And declarative merge is needed since :ref is a child of those merge.

I got help on Clojurian slack from Tommi Reiman ‍♂️
Want to post it here in case someone stumbles upon this.
In essence :merge is not available on the default registry, but we can add it with:
(mr/set-default-registry!
 (mr/composite-registry
  (m/default-schemas) ;; defaults
  (mu/schemas))) ;; utility schemas like :merge

that's it! there rest of the code works. more on that is latest version, as of today 0.16.4, enables schemas like :multi to be mergeable.

